# OpenScap scan results are false-positive

Tags: openscap

I recently ran the OpenScap Audit scan on a SLES 12 machine, and the result seems to be false-positive.

Eg for these two checks :

**1) Ensure sudo logfile exists - sudo logfile**

***The description for this item mentions :***

> A custom log sudo file can be configured with the 'logfile' tag. This
> rule configures a sudo custom logfile at the default location
> suggested by CIS, which uses /var/log/sudo.log.

I have checked in the server, and this entry exists already :

```
ldefra-s12d:~ # grep 'logfile' /etc/sudoers
Defaults logfile="/var/log/sudo.log"
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/multipath -l, /sbin/multipath -ll, /sbin/multipath -r, /sbin/lvs --segments, /usr/bin/salt-call -l quiet cmd.run uname -a, /usr/bin/salt-call -l quiet state.apply test\=true, /usr/bin/zypper --quiet update --dry-run --no-confirm --auto-agree-with-licenses, /usr/bin/yum --quiet check-update, /usr/bin/zypper install --details --dry-run -y TAneo, /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_logfiles, /usr/sbin/crm_mon, /usr/sbin/crm, /usr/sbin/iptables -L -n, /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_iptables.sh, /usr/bin/id, /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_highstate.py, /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_iptables.py
ldefra-s12d:~ #
```

Another one is this :

**2) Limit password reuse**

***The description for this is :***

> Do not allow users to reuse recent passwords. This can be accomplished
> by using the remember option for the pam_pwhistory PAM modules.
>
> In the file /etc/pam.d/common-password, make sure the parameters
> remember and use_authtok are present, and that the value for the
> remember parameter is 5 or greater. For example: password requisite
> pam_pwhistory.so ...existing_options... remember=5 use_authtok The DoD
> STIG requirement is 5 passwords.

In the server, this is also configured :

```
ldefra-s12d:~ # grep remember /etc/pam.d/common-password
password        required        pam_pwhistory.so   use_authtok remember=5 retry=3
```

If this is the case, then why does the scan produce false-positive results? Do I need to edit something from the openscap scanning file/code itself? Please provide a solution for this. It is part of my company's regular audit practice, and I still have no clue on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you run the scan as unprivileged user and could have the file system restrictions prevented the actual evaluation of the contents of your configuration files? Then you might see generic recommendations

Comment: No, the scan is run as root.

Answer (score 1):

The Upstream project for these rules used by OpenSCAP is https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content.

If you believe these rules are not working as expected, it would be great to file an issue there in the project so project maintainers and community can investigate and improve the rules if necessary.

The project is very dynamic and it is likely possible these rules were already updated in the meantime.